# Only one country overlay at a time from table features in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Can anyone help me to overlay the only country on the LST map on Google Earth Engine using the county features table?

```js
// Import counties.
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/Counties")
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('STATEFP', '41'));
print(counties);

// Import LST.
var lst = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
  .filterBounds(counties)
  .filterDate('2020-03-30', '2020-04-29')
  .select('LST_Day_1km');

// Add LST units as degrees c as new band.
var tempToDegrees = lst.map(function(image){
  var degreesC = image.multiply(0.02).subtract(273.15).rename('LST');
  return image.addBands(degreesC);
});

// Make a LST time series per county in FeatureCollection.
var lstTsByCounty = counties.map(function(county) {
  return tempToDegrees.map(function(img) {
    // Reduce precision of county boundaries to match the LST resolution;
    // avoids issues with exceeding memory limit.
    var geom = county.geometry().simplify(1000); 
    var stat = img.select(['LST']).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: geom,
      scale: 1000,
      bestEffort: true,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      tileScale: 4
    });
    return ee.Feature(geom, stat)
      .copyProperties(county, ['NAME'])
      .set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start'));
  });
}).flatten();

// Export the LST time series per county FeatureCollection. The job is
// too big to handle interactively.
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: lstTsByCounty,
  description: 'lstTsByCounty',
  assetId: 'gis_se_q_365561_68793'
});

// After the export finishes- load the FeatureCollection to view the chart.
// You'll need to change the path to your own account.
var lstTs = ee.FeatureCollection("users/nidhivermaiiita/gis_se_q_365561_68793");
print(lstTs.limit(5));

// Chart the LST time series of all the counties.
// If you don't like all of the counties in the same chart,
// filter the lstTs collection by the 'NAME' property. 
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
  features: lstTs,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  yProperty: 'LST',
  seriesProperty: 'NAME'
});
print(chart);

// Display LST to Map.
var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
  bands: ['LST'],
  min: -10,
  max: 35,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};
Map.centerObject(counties);
Map.addLayer(
  tempToDegrees.mean()
  .clipToCollection(counties), landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'LST');

// Display the county boundaries.
var countyLines = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: counties,
  color: 1,
  width: 2
});
Map.addLayer(countyLines, {palette: '000000'}, 'countys');
Map.setOptions('SATELLITE');
```